# What is $\delta$ in this formula?

Tags: dipole-moment

1. What is $\delta$ in the formula below? How can it be evaluated?
2. Is $P$ the expectation value of $cos\theta$?

[image]

[Source](https://orea.opendrive.com/files?Nl80ODA4MDkyMl9OWVEyWQ) (Influence of Hydrophilic Surface Specificity on the Structural Properties of Confined Water; by Ateeque Malani, K. G. Ayappa and Sohail Murad; 2009)

Comment: The $\delta$ is most likely referring to the [Dirac's delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html). This function will return zero for every values excepts at zero, such that when you integrate this function it returns one for every value bigger than zero, also known as the [(heaviside) step function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html). However I am not 100% sure, since I usually see the Dirac's delta function being used by continuous functions/integrals and not integer summations.

Comment: Could you provide the source of the text?

Comment: @fibonatic There is an implied integration here since $\langle\cdot\rangle$ probably means a thermodynamic average, cf. the definition of ordinary density: $\rho(\vec r)=\langle \sum_i\delta(\vec r-\vec x_i)\rangle$. However, the full meaning of the given equation (9) eludes me. Why aren't dipoles with $\theta\neq \pi/2$ counted?

Comment: @KyleKanos, Source added; What is `P`? Expectation or Destiny Function or Probability Distribution?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v4): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann, May you give me a reference for ρ(r⃗)=⟨∑δ(r⃗ −x⃗)⟩? This is near to that formula.

Comment: @mini The wikipedia page on charge density gives a similar expression (in case of discrete charges): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_density#Discrete_charges. It does not contain the thermodynamic average, though.

Answer (score 1):

1) The $\delta$ is very likely a Dirac delta.  However I think there is either a mistake or unclear notation in the formula. Surely the RHS must depend on the orientation of the individual dipoles in the sum - I think the delta function should be $\delta(\cos\theta - \cos\theta_i)$, in order to count the dipoles oriented at angle $\theta$.

For simplicity, let's first consider $P(\theta)$ instead of $P(\cos\theta)$. Let's integrate the expression:

$\int_{\theta_a}^{\theta_b} P(\theta)\ d\theta = \int_{\theta_a}^{\theta_b} \left< \frac{1}{N_l}\sum^{N_l}_{i=1} \delta(\theta - \theta_i) \right> d\theta$

The LHS is, by definition, the total probability of the dipole having orientations in the range $[\theta_a, \theta_b]$. The integral of the delta function will be 1 if $\theta_i$ is within the integration limits, 0 otherwise.

$P(\theta_a < \theta < \theta_b) = \left< \frac{1}{N_l}\sum^{N_l}_{i=1} \{\text{1 if } \theta_a < \theta_i < \theta_b \text{ else 0} \} \right>$

The right hand side now very clearly is counting the fraction of dipoles within the range of angles $[\theta_a, \theta_b]$ for some particular state. The average over states then gives the overall probability.

2) $P$ is NOT the expectation value of $\cos \theta$. It is the probability of a dipole having having orientation $\cos \theta$ relative to the surface normal. The text you posted says this explicitly. Note that $P(\cos \theta)$ is slightly different from the probability as a function of $\theta$, $P(\theta)$, because they are "weighted" differently. The probability of being in corresponding ranges of $\theta$ and $\cos \theta$ is equal, meaning $P(\cos \theta) d\cos\theta = P(\theta)d\theta$ therefore $P(\cos \theta)\sin\theta = P(\theta)$.

Comment: Just a note: I'm really bad at thermodynamics. Not bad with calculus and Dirac delta functions though, which is more what this question is about, I think.

Comment: Is P, the density function? Does P have different meaning In the 1st and 2nd formula: Density Function and Probability Distribution Function?

Comment: @mini $P(\cos\theta)$ is a probability distribution, which you could also call a probability density function; we need probability distributions to describe the probabilities of a continous set of outcomes.  This is very much like recognizing that while a volume of air has mass, a point of air has zero mass but we can still describe the air density at that point. The air density at a point is analagous to $P(\cos\theta)$, and the mass of air in a particular volume is analogous to the probability the dipole orientation is in the range $[\theta_a, \theta_b]$.

Answer (score 0):

I think $\delta$ is the same quantity as $P$ but per molecule.

The entire formula looks like averaging twice.

$\frac{1}{N_l}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_l}...$ is averaging over molecules in layer $l$, and $\langle...\rangle$ is averaging over all layers.

Since $P$ is declared as probability distribution, then $\delta$ is also a probability distribution.

P.S.

Unprobable that $\delta$ is differential, since it is not under integration operator and we don't have differential at left.

Also unprobable that $\delta$ is Dirac function, because it is also useless out of integration.

Comment: Can it be computed into an expanded string?

Comment: What is "expanded string"? If I am right, then the definition of $\delta$ should present somewhere else in textbook. Also it can be unknown or known only by some properties. May be it is possible to suggest that orientation distribution is isotropic.